# Door lock only on one side?

Tags: doors, lock

Guests room has 2 doors:

- One that opens inside the house, to let those already in the house move to guests room.
- One that opens to the outside of the house, to let those outside to get in.

The inside door will have a lock only on the inside.  The guests side will have no key hole, since it is never locked/unlocked from there.  The guests also never need to know if the door is locked, so no need for red/green indicators either.

**Question:** what are the options for such oneside-locked doors?

I thought of cutting a cylinder/barrel in half to eliminate the key hole on the guests side.  But not sure how it works.

I also thought of using door latches, but these have no locks/keys, which might be useful to limit kids going to guests' room without parents' approval (key).

I also thought of digital locks, but they cost a lot in every aspect:  initial and maintenance costs are too high, and replacement parts are too hard to find for the same lock, as they evolve a lot over time, which may require cutting doors again and again to adapt to size variations.

Comment: Have you looked at an ordinary "privacy door knob?"  This is a door knob that lock from the inside, without a key.

Comment: And typically also unlock from the outside with a screwdriver - they provide privacy, not security.  this is the sort of lockset typically used on home bathrooms.

Comment: What about a lever [Mortice lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortise_lock) without a keyhole drilled on the guests side? The key can be removed to prevent locking if needs be too... EDIT: [like this](https://cdn.aws.toolstation.com/images/141020-UK/800/79242.jpg)

Comment: What is the context, are you renting the room out on AirBnB or is this for known guests? I think most AirBnB guests would try all the doors in a room they were staying so I'm not sure it matters if they see a lock on the door, they know it will be locked. I would use a simple one sided cylinder deadbolt. Or for a cheap and simple solution a slide latch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which side of the pond are you? If in Europe, I would use the so-called "half-cylinder" for the door lock:
[image: Half-cylinder door lock]

and just put some filler plates on the guest room side to cover the holes in the door.